# "it will be no fun to watch" or "it will be no fun to watch it"?

Tags: pronouns

"it will be no fun to watch" or "it will be no fun to watch it"?

At first, it looked like a ridiculous question to me, but later, as I thought more, I realized I didn't know the answer. What I need here is not only "yes" or "no" reply, but also the explanation:

> Sadly, women's soccer is improving, which means that soon **it will be
>   no fun to watch** anymore.

or

> Sadly, women's soccer is improving, which means that soon **it will be
>   no fun to watch it** anymore.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are right, for different reasons.

In the first option, the pronoun *it* clearly refers to women's soccer. We can rephrase it as "Women's soccer will be no fun to watch anymore."

In the second option, there are two instances of *it*. The second one refers to women's soccer: "It will be no fun to watch women's soccer anymore." The first one is interesting. It's called a *dummy pronoun,* a pronoun with no antecedent.

Some dummy pronouns don't refer to anything at all (like "it's raining"), but this one actually stands in for the clause "to watch women's soccer," holding its place until it's named later in the sentence. Regular pronouns have to be identified before they're used.

So, when we replace all the pronouns, the two sentences read:

> Women's soccer will be no fun to watch anymore.
>
> To watch women's soccer will be no fun anymore.

Totally different grammatically, but equally valid. I wouldn't say I prefer one of your sentences over the other; both sound equally casual.

Comment: Your second example (using an infinitive as the subject) comes across as extremely formal (AmE); the casual version would be the gerund ("Watching women's soccer will be no fun anymore.").

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I agree, and I wasn't trying to say that would be a good or natural way to phrase it in the least. The original phrasings are fine.

Comment: Ah, okay, I misinterpreted the "both" in your last statement as applying to your examples, but you were referring to "your sentences". I blame lack of sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your sentences are correct.

> 1)...which means that soon it (the soccer game) will be no fun to watch anymore.
>
> 2)...which means that soon it (used as a dummy subject) will be no fun to watch it (the soccer game) anymore.

In the second sentence, the first *it* is used as a dummy subject. “*It*” is used as a dummy subject when the delayed subject is a clause. The delayed subject may be either a to-infinitival clause or an ing-participial clause. A dummy subject often has no meaning, we use it when the real subject is somewhere else in the sentence.

Similar examples:

1. It is obvious that you are going to win the match.
2. It is hard to tell that what he thinks about the soccer game.